# Discord.py Send a message after user reacts to a message

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to make my discord bot send a message as soon as a reaction has been added to a specific message.

This is my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(message, reaction):
    message_id = message.message_id
    channel_id = 830438815595364372
    if message_id == 830439131083046952:
        if reaction.emoji == '':
            await channel.send('OK')
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, when I react to the message, nothing happens.
Thanks in advance.

L.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the [`on_raw_reaction_add()` event reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_raw_reaction_add) takes only one argument, `payload`. The `payload` argument is a [`RawReactionActionEvent` object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.RawReactionActionEvent), which has a few key attributes for solving this issue: [`message_id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.RawReactionActionEvent.message_id) and [`emoji`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.RawReactionActionEvent.emoji).

The `message_id` attribute of the `RawReactionActionEvent` object can be compared to the target Message ID. `RawReactionActionEvent.emoji` is a [`PartialEmoji`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.PartialEmoji) object, which has an attribute [`name`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.PartialEmoji.name), which returns the name of a custom emoji or the unicode representation of a default emoji. This can be compared to the target emoji, whether if it's the emoji copy-pasted or the unicode representation of the emoji.

Finally, [`Client` objects](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#client) have a method [`fetch_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.fetch_channel) which takes the target Channel ID as its only argument and returns a [`GuildChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.abc.GuildChannel) object, which has the `send()` method which we all know and love.

```py
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    message_id = 830439131083046952
    channel_id = 830438815595364372
    if payload.message_id == message_id and payload.emoji.name == "": # OR paylod.emoji.name == u"\U0001F44D"
        channel = await client.fetch_channel(channel_id)
        await channel.send("OK")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I had tried payload (as I use it for role selection) but googling kept getting me back to user and reaction. I'v tried your solution but for some reason I'm still not getting a reply sent to the channel. Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: @Jacbob Lee (forgot the tag)

Comment: So, if I'm reading this correctly, no message is being sent to channel specified by `channel_id`, but no errors are being raised? Are you sure the bot can *see* the channel which the message was sent in?

Comment: Hey @Jacob Lee , it seems as if nothing is happening at all (I issued a print statement to also check in my terminal). I’v tried with different channels as well.

Comment: Are you sure you are reacting to the same message? In the code you provided, the Message ID must be 830439131083046952. If you are reacting to other messages besides that one, then nothing will happen (because the `if` clause will be ignored). Check to make sure that the message you are trying to react to has the same ID as the one assigned to `message_id`.

Comment: How about if you replace the emoji with the Unicode representation?

Comment: Hey @Jacob Lee - I'v tried that and it does nothing. I'v tried different channels, different messages, different emoji's even a different server and it refuses to work, no error code aswel. I'm so confused since I have no idea where to start to find the issue here since there is no error message.

Comment: I found the issue. I had another on_raw_reaction_add (for role selection) function and obviously I had to type my other block of code for the reply when emote is added under it. Thanks for your help and the reply!

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems a bit messed up to me. You have to use `payload` to get it working.

**Have a look at the following code:**

```py
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    # channel and message IDs should be integer:
    if payload.channel_id == ChannelID and payload.message_id == MessageID:
        if str(payload.emoji) == "YourReaction": # Use a string
            channel1 = client.get_channel(MessageChannel)
            await channel1.send("Test")
```

**What did we do?**

- Used `payload`
- Defined the channel and message ID
- Defined the channel where to send the message after the reaction

Comment: You can use `payload.emoji.name` instead of `str(payload.emoji)`.

Comment: Using a `str` is just a shorter version. Both is fine I guess.

Comment: I think it is in most cases, but for custom emojis, I think using `str()` will give the snowflake of the emoji instead of the name of the emoji.